# Python Pygame - updating displays

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working with pygame to try and produce a visual Blackjack game. I'va had a look around for past hour or so, and I can't seem to find anything that does what I'm looking for. I need to update the display (named screen in my code) so that the user can navigate through the menu with ease. the function below is the product of all that I've read up on and, when applied and ran with the necessary button, it only changes the colour of the "Blackjack Blast" text whilst the mouse button is being held down.

```
def update_window():
      textsurface = Font1.render('BlackJack Blast!', True, e_m_lighter)
      screen.blit(textsurface,(106,100))
      pygame.display.update()
```

Could anyone offer any assistance as to how I can get the display to permanently update with a single button press?

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: better learn OOP (Object-Oriented Programing) and then you can create class Button which will remeber state. Your `update_window()` change text but it doesn't remeber it so next time `mainloop` will draw old version.

Comment: see example [button-click-cicle-color](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-click-cycle-color) - it remebers current color in `self.index` so after click it still displays correct color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your code so I will improvise.

You have to use variable which will remeber that you clicked buttom (ie. `clicked = False`) and split code into two part - one will change `clicked`, second will draw different button depend on value in `clicked`

```
# set on start (before mainloop)

clicked = False

# executed when you click in button

def update_window():
  global clicked
  clicked = True    

# in main loop when you draw button

if clicked
  textsurface = Font1.render('BlackJack Blast!', True, e_m_lighter)
else:
  textsurface = Font1.render('BlackJack Blast!', True, NORMAL_COLOR)

screen.blit(textsurface,(106,100))
pygame.display.update()
```

Or you can use variable to keep current image

```
# set on start (before mainloop)

normal_text = Font1.render('BlackJack Blast!', True, NORMAL_COLOR)
clicked_text = Font1.render('BlackJack Blast!', True, e_m_lighter)

current_text = normal_text

# executed when you click in button

def update_window():
  global current_text
  current_text = clicked_text

# in main loop when you draw button

screen.blit(current_text, (106,100))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: I tested this, and it works perfectly fine with changing colours of text, but it doesn't seem to do the same with backgrounds. Well, it changes the background colour, but it doesn't draw over the previously rendered items on the screen. Any advice?

Comment: with background you have to do similar - you have to assign different image or color to some variable in `if clicked` and later use this variable to draw/blit background.

Comment: or maybe you have to clear screen before you draw all elements - `screen.fill( (0,0,0) )`

Comment: BTW: example with [button-hover](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-hover)

Comment: I have a Boolean variable that holds the state of "clicked", and it updates the bckground colour fine, but the previous text and buttons still appear on the screen, even after using `blit()`. I'll try the `screen.fill( (0,0,0) )` when I get back in tomorrow and come back if I discover that not working, Thank you!

Comment: It seems you use `fill()` in wrong place in code or you still draw previous button. You have to create new question with all code.